# Alternative solution for counting the number of ones from 1 to n

Tags: java

I have a question:

> Consider a function which, for a given whole number n, returns the number of ones required when writing out all numbers between 0 and n (inclusive), For example,f(13)=6. Notice that f(1)=1. What is the next largest n such that f(n)=n?

For finding this answer I write a program as follows:

```
/**
 * @author Rakesh KR
 *
 */
public class CountOne {

    public static int countOne(int n){
        int          count;
        StringBuffer strBff = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
            strBff = strBff.append(i);
        }
        count  = strBff.length() - strBff.toString().replace("1", "").length();
        strBff = null;
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=1;i>0;i++){
            if(countOne(i)==i){
                System.out.println("Got it At :: "+ i);
                count++;
            }
            if(count==2)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The program works fine. And after waiting about 1 hour i got answer as `199981`

I am searching for an alternative IDEA for this question (not needed the code). And how can we solve this question in a less time ?

Comment: The number of ones for any given `n` equals the same problem for `n-1` plus the `1`s introduced by `n` itself. So no need to recalculate the whole value for each number again. Just save the old results and account for the new number in each iteration.

Comment: @Sirko mmm - dynamic programming.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It's hardly dynamic programming, it's just common sense.

Comment: @arshajii why can't it be both?

Comment: @arshajii It's a mix of maths and programming, common sense may end up manually counting :P

Comment: *"I am searching for an alternative IDEA for this question (not needed the code). And how can we solve this question in a less time ?"* - So, does "Look it up at http://oeis.org/A014778 " count as an answer here? ;-)

Comment: Use maths first, it seems like every number upto (10^n) -1 (where n >1 ) will have exactly 2*(10^(n-1)) of every digit. That is till 99 (10^2)-1 will have 20 (ie., 2*(10^(2-1)) ) and till 999 (10^3 - 1) there is 200 (2 * 10^(3-1) ) of every digit. Use this to split the number in to powers of 10 and calculate.

Comment: @prajeeshkumar Thanks for giving the mathematical eqn..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arithmetic operations are more efficient than converting to strings and comparing characters.
This code finds the solution in less than 10ms:

```
public class CountOne {

    public static int countOne(int n) {
        int count = 0;
        int mod;
        while (n > 0) {
            mod = n % 10;
            n /= 10;
            if (mod == 1) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 1;
        for (int i = 2;; i++) {
            sum += countOne(i);
            if (sum == i) {
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This returns your "correct" value almost instantly by caching the previous value

```
private static Integer prev = null;

public static int countOneDigit(int num) {
    String s = String.valueOf(num);
    if (s.indexOf('1') < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
        case '1':
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static int countOne(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    if (prev != null) {
        prev += countOneDigit(n);
        return prev;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        count += countOneDigit(i);
    }
    prev = count;
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping all the numbers come up with an Algorithm that could determine required number of 1s, for such Algorithm you have to see and identify a pattern in the number series.

For Example 1-100

- First Number requires 1
- Last Number requires 1
- There is one 1 with every digit in 2nd row (11-19)
- There is one 1 for every row (already calculated ones for 2nd) (21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91)

So 1+1+9+9 = 20

Check Your Answer then expend and test your logic.

So for every Hundred Numbers we require at least ten 1s, now go upto 1000 and 100,000
After exploring the series to a little further you will eventually come up with a Algorithm to determine the required ones without looping all the numbers.

Comment: if you make the numbers as a matrix, you can see there is one 1 in every row and one 1 in every column of one of the rows. Dont forget to count it :)

Comment: I just gave an idea that how one should develop a algorithm